# Pros and Cons of PsychoPy for designing psychological experiments?

Tags: decision-making, software

What are the advantages of using PsychoPy for making an experiment (beyond the fact that it is free and open source)? I do not use psychophysics stimuli (no Gabor for instance); my stimuli are static images or text. Compared to E-Prime for example, how easy is it to set up a basic RT experiment?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I highly recommend PsychoPy over E-prime. Why?

- Keeping track of who has the e-prime dongle is annoying.
- Students learn it more easily (see data below).
- E-prime uses visual basic (boo) and PsychoPy uses Python (yay!).
- PsychoPy easily integrates with R, matlab, and HTML.
- Everyone is doing it... (see data).

Some folks at UCSD did a [survey in summer/fall 2014](http://lpl.ucsd.edu/software-survey-results) asking researchers for their opinions. Here is a summary of the findings.

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1: I had forgotten about the dongle, but this is indeed a big problem. My students keep loosing them once in a while.